# Access level of property in Private Class

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, access-modifiers, access-levels

For Private Class, should i declare my property As Public Or Friend (internal in c#)?
My Private Class is not accessible by any other classes except it parent class.

Comment: What do you mean by parent class? Is you class nested into a class or what?

Comment: Yes is a nested class

Comment: They will be private anyway (because the class is declared private and this will supersede everything else). So you can forget about it in this case.

Comment: @ThomasWeller, They won't be private anyway! Because the class is nested, so the parent can access public and internal members.

Answer (score 2):

In general, try to keep your encapsulation intact. The relationship between your classes should be on "Need to know" basis.

Since I am not familiar with your application design,I am sure I am oversimplifying, but I would ask myself the following question:

- Is the parent class the only class that needs to know the subclass? if so, It should be `private`.
- If not, are all other entities that needs to about know the subclass are in the same project? if so, It should be `internal`.
- If there are entities external to the project that needs to know about the subclass, it should be `public`.

As to the properties. If you decided to have the subclass `private`, there is no use in making the properties `public`.
The only object that can have an instance of the class is the parent class, which is in the same project, and therefore `internal` should be enough for the properties.

**Note**
C# does not have a `friend` modifier. Instead of that you can use `internal`,or The-most similar-yet-less-elegant option: [InternalsVisibleTo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.internalsvisibletoattribute.aspx)

Comment: C# internal == VB Friend.

Comment: @lomed this is not true. `friend` specifies that this class is only accessible by ***ONE***, particular class.
`internal` specifies that this class is accessible by ***ANY*** class in the assembly.

Comment: @lomed care to point the relevant part in the document? it does not relate to `internal` and has an example of `friend` in VB, which does not exist in the same context in C#

Comment: first section: _Specifies that one or more declared programming elements are accessible only from within the assembly that contains their declaration._ see also [Keyword Comparison in Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_C_Sharp_and_Visual_Basic_.NET#Keywords)

Comment: @lomed this might be true for VB (I do not use VB), but not for C#. The header of the document states that the document is talking about VB (**Friend (Visual Basic)**). The tag of the question specifies C#, and in C# `friend` does not exist in the same context.

Comment: Why not edit two three words in your post? The question is about the two languages​​.

Comment: @lomed Modified as per your comment

Answer (score 1):

Since you class (Nested one) is `private` the only one who can access it is its container (the base or parent class). In this case `public` or `internal` (`Friend` in VB) doesn't make any difference, since the only one who can access the nested class is it's parent.
In general, if some day you want to change the access modifier to `public` then its good to foresee it now and choose between `internal` and `public`. Its simple, if you want members of your nested class to be seen only inside the assembly where it defined, then use `internal` otherwise consider using `public`.